# How to install Selenium::Remote::Driver in Ubuntu?

Tags: perl, selenium, ubuntu

I am trying to write a small code but as soon as i am importing "**Selenium::Remote::Driver:**", i get an error stating 
"Can't locate Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm in @INC"

I have tried installing it using below command

```
sudo apt-get install libtest-www-selenium-perl
```

still i get same error

> ```
> $ perl -e 'use Selenium::Remote::Driver;'
> Can't locate Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Selenium::Remote::Driver module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22 /usr/share/perl/5.22 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base .) at -e line 1.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.
> ```

Comment: `libtest-www-selenium-perl` provides `Test::WWW::Selenium` and `WWW::Selenium`.

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium::Remote::Driver](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver) is not part of [Test::WWW::Selenium](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::WWW::Selenium). From the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/source/GEMPESAW/Selenium-Remote-Driver-0.2701/INSTALL.md):

> Installation
>   It's probably easiest to use the `cpanm` or `CPAN`
>   commands:   `bash $ cpanm Selenium::Remote::Driver`